# What are the differences and gotchas when changing SQL Server compat mode from 90 to 100?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, configuration

I would like to know what the implications for my database might be to swap from compat mode 90 (2005) to 100 (2008). Are there any performance enhancements? Are there any deprecated features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility mode doesn't have anything to do with performance or similar. It's just the syntax of T-SQL on what it allows and don't allow

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct performance benefits, but the behaviour of TSQL is different. The topic "[ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)" in Books Online lists the differences between level 100 and previous levels.