# SQL Server Compatibility level implications

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, compatibility

A quick information question :

On my SQL Server 2008, I have databases migrated from SQL Server 2005 and the Compatibility level of the databases on SQL Server 2008 are set to `90` (SQL Server 2005).

What exactly are the implications of that?

It means that the migrated stored procedures, triggers and functions will work well on SQL Server 2008, but are there any disadvantages?

What could be the reason to set the compatibility level to `100` (SQL Server 2008) ?

Performance? Extra features?

Thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences and gotchas when changing SQL Server compat mode from 90 to 100?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351312/what-are-the-differences-and-gotchas-when-changing-sql-server-compat-mode-from-9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compatibility mode is there to help people migrate applications that have functions that are no longer compatible with newer versions of SQL. If you have applications that require functions no longer supported in sql 2008 you would want to run them in compatibility mode; otherwise you would like use a current sql mode. Our business runs an application that due to the way it connects to the database  requires SQL 2000 compatibility mode; but it is running on a SQL 2012 server.

Specific functions in code might impact performance as the required logic is different rather than the execution is specifically different. As a very generalised rule SQL code optimised for functions on 2012,2008 would be quicker than SQL 2000 or SQL 7 as they have added things like CTE and un/pivot both of which allow for simplified coding.

Answer (score 1):

Other than inability to use any new features which include behind the scenes ones as the improvements in the Query Optimizer (in SQL Server 2014), staying behind in compatibility mode makes future upgrades more difficult.
MSDN has a list of is different between editions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Never assume that backing up and restoring a database to a newer instance is all that is needed to migrate a database. This is the cause of many hidden and unexpected application errors. If your application gives errors after a database restore, look at its compatibility level. If it has changed, this may be the cause.
The act of changing the compatibility level tells the database to change its feature set. That is, some features will be added, but at the same time some old features will be removed. For example, The FOR BROWSE clause is not allowed in INSERT and SELECT INTO statements at compatibility level 100 but it is allowed but ignored at compatibility level 90. So if your application uses this feature, this change may introduce unexpected results.

This [website](https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/web-applications/understanding-sql-server-compatibility-levels) can give a lot of information about compatibility level, its advantages and disadvantages plus a big set of best practices.